# AbortKernels, CloseKernels may crash Mathematica

Tags: bugs, parallelization

Let us start with a variant of an example in the documentation of `AbortKernels`.

We launch four subkernels:

```
LaunchKernels[4];
```

We create four simple evaluation objects. Each of them is an infinite loop, increasing a common shared variable after a random time. While showing the value of the shared variable, we parallel evaluate the tasks until we manually abort the evaluation.

```
found=0.;
SetSharedVariable[found];
tasks=Table[ParallelSubmit[While[True, Pause[RandomReal[]];found=found+1]], {4}]
PrintTemporary[Dynamic[found]];
CheckAbort[WaitAll[tasks], AbortKernels[]];
found
```

Run the above command and abort manually a number of times. Ultimately, *Mathematica* will hang. When this happens is highly inpredictable. In my tests, it varied from 1 (immediate hanging) to 8 (7 succesfull abortions).

The problem also turns up when we use `CloseKernels` instead of `AbortKernels`. Run and abort the next command a number of times.

```
LaunchKernels[4];
Dynamic[Kernels[], UpdateInterval->1]
found=0.;
SetSharedVariable[found];
tasks=Table[ParallelSubmit[While[True, Pause[RandomReal[]];found=found+1]], {4}]
PrintTemporary[Dynamic[found]];
CheckAbort[WaitAll[tasks], CloseKernels[]];
found
```

When *Mathematica* hangs after abortion, it seems theat the subkernels are not closed.

It has nothing to with evaluation objects, as is shown in the next command:

```
LaunchKernels[4];
found=0.;
SetSharedVariable[found];
PrintTemporary[Dynamic[found]];
CheckAbort[ParallelDo[Pause[RandomReal[]];found=found+1, {10000}], CloseKernels[]];
found
```

WRI CASE:4041721, 2018-04-16.

Comment: I can reproduce the issues with Mma 11.3.0 on Win 8.1 Pro.  I agree that it seems like the hanging could be a bug.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it now, the title of my question should be: Aborting a parallel computation with a shared variable may crash *Mathematica*. It seems to have nothing to do with `AbortKernels` or `CloseKernels`. I was mislead by the example in the documentation of `AbortKernels`, in which, after aborting a parallel computation, a command `AbortKernels[]` was given.

The following example suggests that aborting a parallel computation also aborts the subkernels, so that giving a command `AbortKernels` after `Abort` is superfluous.

First open `Parallel Kernel Status`. That launches four subkernels. Then 
evaluate the next cell.

```
found=0;
DistributeDefinitions[found];
tasks=Table[ParallelSubmit[While[True, Pause[RandomReal[]];found=found+1]], {4}]
WaitAll[tasks]
```

`Parallel Kernel Status` shows that the four subkernels are running. After some time, abort the computation. Then `Parallel Kernel Status` shows that the four subkernels become idle. (In 15 attempts no crash of *Mathematica*.) We can inspect the result by using `ParallelEvaluate`:

```
ParallelEvaluate[found]
(* {31,34,32,28} *)
```

Now let us introduce a shared variable.

```
found=0.;
SetSharedVariable[found];
tasks=Table[ParallelSubmit[While[True, Pause[RandomReal[]];found=found+1]], {4}]
PrintTemporary[Dynamic[found]];
WaitAll[tasks]
found
```

All assignments to the shared variable are done by the main kernel. When we abort the above computation, it seems that first the main kernel is aborted and a little bit later the subkernels. In the mean time, it might happen that a subkernel asks the main kernel to do an assignment, which now is impossible. In that case, *Mathematica* will crash. Indeed, after some attempts, aborting the above command crashes *Mathematica*.

A better way of aborting the above parallel computation is to abort the subkernels manually. To this end, create the following button and run the above command once again.

```
Button["Abort kernels", AbortKernels[]]
```

When we press the button, `Parallel Kernel Status` shows that the subkernels become idle. As a consequence, the execution of `WaitAll` finishes and the value of the variable `found` is returned.

This seems to be a safe way of aborting a parallel computation. But it is not absolutely safe: a subkernel can be aborted during the proces of assigning to the shared variable. In that case, this subkernel dies, but *Mathematica* does not crash. When we rerun the command, the died subkernel will be replaced by a new one.